# Is there a better way of doing a git stash pop and then discard the stashed changes if I don't merge?

Tags: git

Sometimes I `git pop` and get things I don't want to merge and want to throw away. Is there a better way throwing away that stash than what I'm currently doing:

```
git stash pop
```

*Decide I don't want the stash.*

```
git reset HEAD
git checkout -- .
git stash drop
```

If I pop but don't merge the stash stays, which is why I drop it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to do the `git reset HEAD` and `git checkout --` etc ( which in itself is verbose, as you can just do `git reset --hard` to get a clean working directory) to drop a stash. You just have to do `git stash drop` and the stash will be dropped. Note that when you pop and git can't apply cleanly, the stash is not popped and is still there. You are then dropping it after cleaning up, which is not necessary.

You might also want to use the `branch` option of `git stash` if you are facing lots of conflicts. It will create a new branch off the HEAD where you stashed.

Answer (score 1):

Are there two stashes? How are you popping *and* dropping it? (Or is this why you mention merge - it doesn't apply cleanly?)

In any case, `git reset HEAD; git checkout -- .`, assuming you're at the top level of your repo, is the same thing as just `git reset --hard` - that makes your index and work tree match the current commit. (`HEAD` is never necessary as an argument for `git reset`; it's the default.)

If the stash needs dropping, you'll still have to drop it, though.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't apply cleanly. I want to get rid of all the changes in the stash, but I won't know that before I pop (happens once in a while when I have old code lingering in my stash). I didn't know about `HEAD` being default, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

git reset --hard HEAD

will get you back to a clean working directory and index that matches HEAD. the only problem is if you 'git stash pop'd you'll lose this stash forever.

If you think you might still want this stash, use 'git stash apply' which keeps this stash in the stash stack.